# No feed back message when run functions that suppose to generates msg

Tags: emacs

I recently updated all the packages of my emacs 24.3 under Windows, and I found strangely that now there is no feed back message when run functions that is supposed to generates messages. e.g, when i run M-x org-version, just no message shows up either in the minibuffer or in the *Message* buffer. but other messages like errors, mark sets, saving/loading are all there. it would be tedious for me to try to figure out which package causes the problem, so I hope some one here can give some clue.
the packages i have are

```
ace-jump-mode ack-and-a-half anzu dash diminish elisp-slime-nav
expand-region flx-ido flycheck gist
git-commit-mode gitconfig-mode gitignore-mode grizzl
guru-mode helm helm-projectile ido-ubiquitous
key-chord magit move-text rainbow-mode
smartparens smex undo-tree
volatile-highlights zenburn-theme
```

thanks

Comment: Is your `org` package also installed with `M-x list-packages`, or are you using only the stock `org` package distributed with Emacs 24.3?

Comment: well, i solved this by switching back to emacs 24.3 32bit version, previously i use x64 version, dont know why but now the problem is gone

Comment: Sounds like you should consider filing an Org mode bug. Should it not work also with a 64-bit version?

Comment: that is  not only happen to the command org-version, but all command that suppose to give msg in minibuffer...